# How to determine the permissible values for which solution of the Schrödinger's wave equation exists?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, atoms

My textbook( [A Textbook of Physical Chemistry, Dr. O.P. Tandon](http://www.bathlabooks.com/admin/pages/Upload/Title/A%20Textbook%20Of%20Physical%20Chemistry%20for%20Competitions-JEE.jpg) ) says that  solution of the  Schrödinger's wave equation exists only for certain permissible values which are called eigen values.( physically possible ones).

How to determine the permissible solutions of the wave equation? Please explain.

Comment: Either the textbook or your quote is somewhat misleading. It is akin to saying that there are many solutions to the equation $x-5=0$, but only certain solution (that is, $x=5$) is "permissible" (that is, right).

Comment: @IvanNeretin thanks for pointing out, I have corrected it.

Comment: My comment still applies. Also, eigenvalues are surely **not** the solutions to the wave equation, either permissible or otherwise.

Comment: @IvanNeretin is this OK now, if not please correct me.

Comment: Now it's OK. You have that E (energy) in the equation; it is just some number, but it can't be _any_ number. There are certain permissible values for it, AKA eigenvalues.

Comment: Mathematically there is nothing special about the Schrodinger equation as a differential equation. It is the *boundary conditions* we apply based on the physical situation, say length of box for particle in a box, that leads to quantised solutions, i.e. eigenvalues.